# CDN for your entire site - when the origin server equals the supername

Tags: apache, .htaccess, static, cdn

I am using a static site generator for my site, that means my entire site is static. All my resources and HTML files are referenced with the domain name prefixed, so that the CDN could be used.

But due to SEO concerns I disabled non-www access and redirect those to the www.domain.com variant. But now I cannot use a CDN apparently, because the origin server needs to be different from the supername.

Can a CDN be used for HTML files?
How can I deliver content through www.domain.com and use a CDN?
Can I give the CDN access to static.domain.com an an origin server, but deny access to other clients? *Seems clumsy!*

Any ideas?

Using Apache2.2 trying to use Level 3 CDN through my hosting company's site

Answer (score 0):

depending what you are able to set on the CDN via your hosting company, the best way would be to override the host header on the CDN settings.
So, first let's look at your DNS settings:

- www should point to the CDN
- origin should point to your web server.

Now, on the CDN you set your origin to origin.yourdomain.com and add (I can't tell you if this is possible in your setup) a "http host header override" to www.yourdomain.com. In some cases it's implemented the other way around, so you would "force IP-Host" to origin.yourdomain.com.

In both cases, what you want to achieve is this:

- when an end user requests www.yourdomain.com , it is resolved to the CDN
- The CDN needs to fetch the content from your server, so it establishes a session on port 80 (assuming HTTP) to origin.yourdomain.com
- Once the port is open, the CDN sends (amongst others) a HTTP Host-Header with www.yourdomain.com (this is the name based virtual host APache is seeing and evaluating).

That way you can set up your web server in exactly the same way as you would without a CDN.